# JS Paths when deploying to heroku

Tags: jquery, angularjs, heroku, bower, mean-stack

I currently have a mean application which runs fine locally. But when deploying to heroku i get 404 errors when trying to load libraries such as angularjs, jquery etc.

In my index.html file I currently have files added as follows:

```
<!-- build:js({client,node_modules}) app/vendor.js -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
```

The structure in my solution is client/bower_componenets. The .bowerrc states this path as well.

When loading the app from heroku instance the path is erroring with 404

https://app.herokuapp.com/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Any ideas would be great